# What for is IsSchemaBound view's setting in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference for a view if it is schema bounded or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a view is schema bound, it means that the underlying schemas cannot change. It actually prevents it from doing so.

Schema binding also allows you to index a view. You can see the importance of a static schema when applying indices.

Keep in mind that a schema binding can only take place within a database--you can't schema bind a view to another database or another server. This is entirely for data integrity reasons--you're not always guaranteed to have access to that database or server, so therefore, you cannot prevent any and all changes to the schema.

Moreover, you can't drop a table that's schema bound. This will obviously muck up its schema, so is therefore prevented.

While I keep saying, "schema," I mean the table design. This includes the columns and their data types. You cannot change a column from `int` to `bigint` on a schema bound table. Nor can you change a column's name from `id` to `tblID`. This prevention is meant solely to uphold the integrity of the view.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot index a view which is not schema bound.

A schema bound view is a part of schema dependency chains.

You cannot drop or alter a table which is referenced by a schema bound view, but can do it on a plain view (which will just throw a runtime error when referenced).

Answer (score 1):

> The main benefit of SCHEMA BINDING is
>   to avoid any accidental drop or change
>   of an object that is referenced by
>   other objects

[Using schema binding to improve SQL Server UDF performance](http://www.mssqltips.com/tipprint.asp?tip=1692)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great explanation on the WITH SCHEMABINDING option int the [Microsoft® SQL Server ®
2012 T-SQL Fundamentals](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/book.aspx?id=15065&) by Itzik Ben-Gan, and in the [Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/training-kit-exam-70-461-querying-microsoft-sql-server-9780735666054) by Dejan Sarka, Itzik Ben-Gan, and more authors.

Here's an example when you try to drop an object or a column from an object created with the WITH SCHEMABINDING option:

Create a simple view using the WITH SCHEMABINDING option, than try to alter it e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE Table DROP COLUMN Column1;
```

You’ll get the following error:

*Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'SomeObject' is dependent on column 'Column1'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Column1 failed because one or more objects access this column.*

If you had a view without the SCHEMABINDING option, this change would be allowed but it may lead to errors at run time if you query an object with a dropped object or a column.

The SCHEMABINDING option also has some preferences as it doesn't support the SELECT * syntax and you have to use qualified names (two-name convention).

Hope this helps